# How to add a "say" message to the beginning of conference using Twilio API in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, url, twilio, ngrok

This is my code and it is working perfectly for creating a conference by calling two numbers. However, I wanted to add a message at the beginning of the conference to say "Hello, you will be contacted shortly"

I read that I can use ngrok to create the URL with the XML response but ngrok is not working for me. because ngrok urls are only working for me when the code is still running locally. so If I stop the Twilio script that I wrote to generate this URL from running locally the ngrok URL stops working.

```
function CallTwilio(number1, number2) {

const Twilio = require('twilio');

var accountSid = 'XXX';
var  authToken = 'YYY';
const client =  Twilio (accountSid, authToken);


  [number1, number2].forEach(function(number_i) {
    client.calls.create({
    url: 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH05a82ce144a55344f0d39ac6b20204f1',
      to: number_i,
      from: 'mynumber',
    })
    .then((call) => onprogress.stdout.write('Called'));
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I note that when you create the call you pass a `url` which is a [TwiML Bin](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins). My guess is that your TwiML Bin code looks a bit like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial><Conference>Conference name</Conference></Dial>
</Response>
```

If you want to [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) a message before the person you call enters the conference, then you need to adjust this to include the `<Say>` before the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial). Like this:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Hello, you will be connected shortly.</Say>
  <Dial><Conference>Conference name</Conference></Dial>
</Response>
```